# How to check if my table has a specific letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

We have a table and we are supposed to check if it has a letter given by the user and so I wrote a small code that works for one list but when I run it for the table it gives me false.

```
table = [['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
         ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
         ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
         ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
         ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*']]

def print_table():
  for row in range(5):
    for col in range(5):
        print(table[row][col],end="")
    print("")
def table_has_letter(letter):
  if (letter in table):
    print('true')
  else:
    print("false")
table_has_letter("'*'")
```

I tried attaching a variable to print_table() and trying to use the variable in the code looking for the letter but it says "Argument of NoneType are not iterable". Thanks in advance.

Comment: The letter is `*` not `'*'` :) You have a pair of quotation marks too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table = [['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
        ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
        ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
        ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
        ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*']]

def print_table():
    print('\n'.join(['\t'.join(x) for x in table]))

def table_has_letter(letter):
    return any(letter in x for x in table)

print(table_has_letter('*'))
```

Comment: Updated for you bby ;)

Comment: shouldn't be `return any(letter in x for x in table)` be enough ?

Answer (score 1):

You have lists inside your table so you need to iterate through each element of table to check letters:

```
def table_has_letter(letter):
    for element in table:
        if letter in element:
            return True
    return False
print (table_has_letter('*')) # not "'*'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have actually did two logical mistakes in your code:
1) You are trying to check the letter in the table list but not in the actual rows of the table list therefore you are not getting True there.
2) You are trying to check '*' not * both are different things as python is concerned.
For reference below is my modified code of your table_has_letter() method

```
    def table_has_letter(letter):
        for rows in table:    
            if (letter in rows):
                return True 
        return False
    print table_has_letter("*")
```